# How to cache .mxd without data frame's background?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, cache

I'm trying to cache a map document in ArcGIS in order to upload it later to my ArcGIS Online account. My map document (.mxd) contains several layers - most of them are from the same feature class. The layers differs from one another in their symbology and labeling according to specific extents (I've defined an extent interval for each layer specifically). The feature class projection is defined as GCS_WGS_1984.
In order to do so I've made a 1. [Scheme](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000188000000) with the Generate Tile Cache Tiling Scheme (Data Management) tool 2. and then tried to create a [cache](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Manage_Tile_Cache/001700000189000000/) with the Manage Tile Cache (Data Management) tool.

I've encountered two major problems:
1. After creating the cache, I've added it to my map document. The cache had a **blocked** (not-transparent) **background** (in the color of the data frame's background).
2. The cached raster that I've added, didn't contained the **full extent** of the .mxd's layers.

My questions are this:
**1. How to make the caching procedure to omit the blocked background?
2. How to make the final cache in the .mxd's full layers extent?**

I've tried about 15-25 attempts to do so. They included drawing a specific AREA OF INTEREST, transformations of the projections of the data frame's layer, using a default symbology for the layers (which worked but had a bad symbology), disabling the maplex engine, define a full extent for the data frame and more.